# Puppet standalone error - Unknown resource type: 'testme_service::install'

Tags: puppet

I'm fairly new to puppet and I'm testing the puppet Roles and Profiles strategy (in puppet standalone mode), but I'm running into an error.

I built a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to illustrate the problem.  The goal of this example is just to confirm a file in /tmp.

I start the test with:

- `sudo /opt/puppetlabs/bin/puppet apply --noop -t -d -e "include role::testme_service"`.

However, when I run that command, I keep getting an error saying:

```
Error: Evaluation Error: Error while evaluating a Resource Statement, 
Unknown resource type: 'testme_service::install' (file: 
/opt/puppetlabs/puppet/modules/profile/manifests/init.pp,
line: 3, column: 5)`
```

The good news is I'm executing the Role code, and it references back to the Profile definition.

However, I don't understand that `Unknown resource` error because I already defined `testme_service::install` in the `testme_service` module.

This is probably a PEBKAC issue, but I don't understand how to fix the error (puppet's directories still seem a little magical to me).

### Question

I'm running puppet5.5 on Ubuntu 18... Could someone give me some pointers on how to fix the problem(s), and explain what I should be doing if I've built this Roles and Profiles test incorrectly?

### Overview: directory structure

```
ubuntu@test-04:/opt/puppetlabs/puppet/modules$ pwd
/opt/puppetlabs/puppet/modules

ubuntu@test-04:/opt/puppetlabs/puppet/modules$
ubuntu@test-04:/opt/puppetlabs/puppet/modules$ tree
.
├── profile
│   ├── data
│   ├── files
│   ├── manifests
│   │   ├── init.pp
│   │   └── site.pp
│   └── templates
├── README.md
├── role
│   ├── data
│   ├── files
│   ├── manifests
│   │   └── init.pp
│   └── templates
└── testme_service
    ├── data
    ├── files
    ├── manifests
    │   └── init.pp
    └── templates

15 directories, 5 files
ubuntu@test-04:/opt/puppetlabs/puppet/modules$
```

### File contents:

*`profile/manifests/init.pp`* has

```
class profile::testme_service {

    testme_service::install { "install the testme_service config in /tmp":
      version => '0.0.1-foo-the-bar',
    }

}
```

*`profile/manifests/site.pp`* has

```
node /^test-04/ {
    include profile::testme_service
}

node default {
  fail("Hit the default node in profile... could not find the correct per-node profile")
}
```

*`role/manifests/init.pp`* has

```
class role::testme_service {

  include profile::testme_service

}
```

*`testme_service/manifests/init.pp`* has

```
# implement testme_service::install
class testme_service::install (
  String $version = '__broken_default__',
) {

  file { '/tmp/testme.conf':
    ensure  => file,
    owner   => 'root',
    content => "version: $version",
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Solution A: Call `testme_service::install` a different way in `profile`

- `profile/manifests/init.pp`

```
class profile::testme_service {
    class { "testme_service::install":
      version => '0.0.1-foo-the-bar',
    }
}
```

#### Solution B: Works but a coworker discouraged this solution...

- Using `define ...` instead of `class ...` in `testme_service/manifests/init.pp` also fixed the problem...

```
# implement testme_service::install
define testme_service::install (
  String $version = '__broken_default__',
) {

  file { '/tmp/testme.conf':
    ensure  => file,
    owner   => 'root',
    content => "version: $version",
  }

}
```